# Installing conda package from a private GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, conda

I'm trying to install a conda package from a private Google Cloud Storage bucket. I managed to do it from a public bucket by following this procedure:

1. Create the .tar.bz2 package locally.
2. Run [indexing](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/create-custom-channels.html) the package.
3. Copy the contents to GCS.
4. Add the bucket to the .condarc file:

```
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
  - https://storage.googleapis.com/my-channel
```

5. Run `conda install my_package`.

I haven't managed to make it work when the bucket is private. I tried it with a signed URL that I get by creating a Service Account and using:

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    json.loads('my-service-account-key.json'),
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only"]
)

client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project='your-project-id')
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(object_path)


url = blob.generate_signed_url(
    version="v4",
    expiration=3600,
    api_access_endpoint="https://storage.googleapis.com"
)
```

But I still get `UnavailableInvalidChannel: HTTP 403 FORBIDDEN`. How can I use the correct credentials so that I will be able to install the package with conda?